# add function to other sibling divs but not the hovered div after certain time (jquery & javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 3 divs, how can I make it so that when I hover one div, say after 3 seconds the other 2 divs gets fadeTo but not the one I hovered?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

inside the hover/enter function : $(this).siblings().fadeOut()

For example:

```
$('.the-divs').mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).siblings().fadeOut(); // or whatever animation, eventually with delay()
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to position the divs such that when the others fade out the remaining div doesn't move, in my example I set the div's to absolute positioning.

[example](http://jsfiddle.net/pxfunc/YmTdG/)

```
var $threeDivs = $('#container > div');

$threeDivs.hover(function () { // mouseover
    $(this).siblings().stop(true, true).fadeOut();
}, function() { // mouseout
    $(this).siblings().stop(true, true).fadeIn();
});
```